# application cannot be installed on API 21

Tags: android

I just made an application using Android Studio 3.6, I tested using API 29, the application can be installed, but when I ask my friend to test on his device (Android 6.0) the application is not installed, so my application can only be installed on Android 7.0 and above, I want old Android users to be able to use my application. This is build.gradle that I use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    ...
}
```

I have tried to downgrade the target SDK but it still cannot be installed

Comment: you might be relying on a dependency that requires android 7.0 and up

Comment: I also think so, but when I test using AVD API 22 it works